# php array_push overwriting values

Tags: php, arrays

From sql I create an array $sails that look like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => RES
            [date] => 2022-05-14
            [doy] => 133
            [skipperid] => 217
            [boat] => Laura
            [start] => 09:00:00
            [end] => 22:00:00
            [spots] => 5
            [fname] => David
            [lname] => Cross
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [type] => SAIL
            [date] => 2022-05-14
            [doy] => 133
            [skipperid] => 1
            [boat] => Avrora
            [start] => 10:00:00
            [end] => 13:00:00
            [spots] => 3
            [fname] => Bob
            [lname] => Smith
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [type] => RES
            [date] => 2022-05-24
            [doy] => 143
            [skipperid] => 1
            [boat] => Irlbach
            [start] => 09:00:00
            [end] => 13:30:00
            [spots] => 3
            [fname] => Bob
            [lname] => Smith
        )

)
```

I want to convert this to an object of arrays of objects.  Essentially something that looks like

```
{[{},{}],[{}]}
```

Here's what I am trying:

```
$allSails =  new stdClass();    
$sailCnt = count($sails);

for($i = 0; $i < $sailCnt; $i++){    
    $dayKey = $sails[$i]['doy']; 
    $allSails->$dayKey = array();

    $itmCnt = count($sails[$i]);    
    $keys = array_keys($sails[$i]);    
    $items = new stdClass();   
    $j = 0;

    foreach($keys as $key){    
        $items->$key = $sails[$i][$keys[$j]];    
        $j++;    
    }
    array_push($allSails->$dayKey, clone $items);    
}
```

but this is the output:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [133] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [type] => SAIL
                    [date] => 2022-05-14
                    [doy] => 133
                    [skipperid] => 1
                    [boat] => Avrora
                    [start] => 10:00:00
                    [end] => 13:00:00
                    [spots] => 3
                    [fname] => Bob
                    [lname] => Smith
                )
        )
    [143] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [type] => RES
                    [date] => 2022-05-24
                    [doy] => 143
                    [skipperid] => 1
                    [boat] => Irlbach
                    [start] => 09:00:00
                    [end] => 13:30:00
                    [spots] => 3
                    [fname] => Bob
                    [lname] => Smith
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: You can easily convert an array to an object like this: `$items = (object) $sails[$i];`

Comment: Also, to loop an array you can just do `foreach($sails[$i] as $sail) {...}`, and if you need the key do `foreach($sails[$i] as $key => $sail) {...}`

Comment: Lastly, to explain why it wasn't working as you expected, the issue wasn't `array_push` but this portion of code: `$allSails->$dayKey = array();`. It was always setting the key to an empty array and you need to do it just once (like in the various solutions given, first check if it doesn't exist, create the empty array, if it already exist just add more elements to it).

Comment: @Gonzalingui yep, you nailed it.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a clean-up of the OP's code:

```
$sails = [
    ['type' => 'RES', 'date' => '2022-05-14', 'doy'  => '133', 'skipperid' => '217', 'boat' => 'Laura', 'start' => '09:00:00', 'end'  => '22:00:00', 'spots'  => '5', 'fname'  => 'David', 'lname'  => 'Cross'],
    ['type' => 'SAIL', 'date' => '2022-05-14', 'doy'  => '133', 'skipperid' => '1', 'boat' => 'Avrora', 'start'  => '10:00:00', 'end'  => '13:00:00', 'spots'  => '3', 'fname'  => 'Bob', 'lname'  => 'Smith',],
    ['type' => 'RES', 'date' => '2022-05-24', 'doy'  => '143', 'skipperid' => '1', 'boat' => 'Irlbach', 'start'  => '09:00:00', 'end'  => '13:30:00', 'spots'  => '3', 'fname'  => 'Bob', 'lname'  => 'Smith',],
];

$allSails = new stdClass();

foreach($sails as $sail) {
  $dayKey = $sail['doy'];
  if (!array_key_exists($dayKey, (array)$allSails)) {
    $allSails->{$dayKey} = [];
  }
  $items = new stdClass();
  foreach ($sail as $key => $value) {
    $items->{$key} = $value;
  }
  $allSails->$dayKey[] = $items;
}

print_r($allSails);
```

Comment: makes sense but it didn't work

Comment: I just added the $sails array. With that I get the desired output here.

Comment: do you have a reference for $obj->$key[]  I haven't seen that before.  why does adding [] make it add sequentially and without it override what's there?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php. The second note says: _If you use array_push() to add one element to the array, it's better to use $array[] = because in that way there is no overhead of calling a function._

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = [
    ['type' => 'RES', 'date' => '2022-05-14', 'doy'  => '133', 'skipperid' => '217', 'boat' => 'Laura', 'start' => '09:00:00', 'end'  => '22:00:00', 'spots'  => '5', 'fname'  => 'David', 'lname'  => 'Cross'],
    ['type' => 'SAIL', 'date' => '2022-05-14', 'doy'  => '133', 'skipperid' => '1', 'boat' => 'Avrora', 'start'  => '10:00:00', 'end'  => '13:00:00', 'spots'  => '3', 'fname'  => 'Bob', 'lname'  => 'Smith',],
    ['type' => 'RES', 'date' => '2022-05-24', 'doy'  => '143', 'skipperid' => '1', 'boat' => 'Irlbach', 'start'  => '09:00:00', 'end'  => '13:30:00', 'spots'  => '3', 'fname'  => 'Bob', 'lname'  => 'Smith',],
];

$result = [];

array_walk($data, function ($item) use (&$result) {
  $obj = new stdClass();
  foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
    $obj->{$key} = $value;
  }
  $result[$obj->doy][] = $obj;
});

print_r($result);
```

If you really want to put these into a wrapper object instead of an array amend it to look like this:

```
$result = new stdClass();   // Changed this line

array_walk($data, function ($item) use (&$result) {
  $obj = new stdClass();
  foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
    $obj->{$key} = $value;
  }
  $result->{$obj->doy}[] = $obj;   // Changed this line
});
```

Comment: thanks but this doesn't explain why my code isn't working.

Comment: _$result->$dayKey = [];_ is the problem in your code.

Comment: How do you fix it?

Comment: Only assign [] if _$result->$dayKey_ does not exist.

Comment: $daykey always exists.  This makes no sense

Comment: Of course it makes sense. Check out the second answer I just posted.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing simple casting?

```
$object=(object) $sails
```

If that does not work, you can use a JSON shortcut:

```
$json=json_encode($sails, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)
$object=json_decode($json, false)
```

Comment: not a clue on how to try this.  On what?

Comment: Clearly on your array `$sails`.